# WPF Access XML in <Window.Resource> from Code

Tags: c#, xml

This is one of the tutorials on Microsoft about data binding with XML. I am using the source code provided on the web page.

In the application. It creates an XML in Window.Resources and data binding with other controls.

#### Xaml

```
<Window.Resources>
        <!-- Books provider and inline data -->
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="LoadedBooks" ObjectType="{x:Type linq:XElement}" MethodName="Parse">
            <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                <system:String xml:space="preserve">
<![CDATA[
<books xmlns="http://www.mybooks.com">
  <book id="0">book zero</book>
  <book id="1">book one</book>
  <book id="2">book two</book>
  <book id="3">book three</book>
</books>
]]>
                </system:String>
                <linq:LoadOptions>PreserveWhitespace</linq:LoadOptions>
            </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        </ObjectDataProvider>
...
</Window.Resouces>

// Other UI data binding code...
<StackPanel> ....
```

The XAML runs perfectly. Control can display the XML data correctly. However, in the code behind, it should load the XML data as XElement. So I can use a button click event to add/remove node.

#### CS

```
    public partial class L2XDBForm : Window
    {
        XNamespace mybooks = "http://www.mybooks.com";
        XElement bookList;

        public L2XDBForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // load xml data
            bookList = (XElement) this.FindResource("LoadedBooks");

        }

        void OnAddBook(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbAddID.Text) ||
                String.IsNullOrEmpty(tbAddValue.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please supply both a Book ID and a Value!", "Entry Error!");
                return;
            }
            XElement newBook = new XElement(
                mybooks + "book",
                new XAttribute("id", tbAddID.Text),
                tbAddValue.Text);
            bookList.Add("  ", newBook, "\r\n");
        }
// other event handler...
```

However, it shows *System.InvalidCastException:“Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Data.ObjectDataProvider' to type 'System.Xml.Linq.XElement'.”*

It seems I cannot get Window.Resources xml object from code `bookList = (XElement) this.FindResource("LoadedBooks");`

And move on to the Remove button to delete node.

#### Remove Node from XML

```
        void OnRemoveBook(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = lbBooks.SelectedIndex;
            if (index < 0) return;

            XElement selBook = (XElement)lbBooks.SelectedItem;
            //Get next node before removing element.
            XNode nextNode = selBook.NextNode;
            selBook.Remove();

            //Remove any matching newline node.
            if (nextNode != null && nextNode.ToString().Trim().Equals(""))
            { nextNode.Remove(); }

            //Set selected item.
            if (lbBooks.Items.Count > 0)
            { lbBooks.SelectedItem = lbBooks.Items[index > 0 ? index - 1 : 0]; }
        }
```

This code works well. I can transfer a selected item as an XElement. So my question is, is there a better way to add the node or access the XML from Window.Resource? Should I transfer all the items in Listbox to an XElement object?

Thanks!

Comment: The response is text so you need to parse the text :  XElement bookList = XElement.Parse(text);

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think I found a solution. In the constructor, put `bookList = (XElement)((ObjectDataProvider)Resources["LoadedBooks"]).Data;}`

Comment: I think you object is text.  So just parse will work.